# Docker container not seeing files in volume on the host

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I have a docker container running which I have created with volumes on the host. I can see the files in the container but whenever I try to access the file from the browser, I get a "not found" error".

Here is my docker file:

```
FROM ubuntu:12.04
    MAINTAINER james M <jamesmod_23@gmail.com>

RUN apt-get update RUN apt-get -y install apache2 \ php5 \ php5-mysql \ php5-gd \ php5-curl \ php5-imagick \ php5-imap \ php5-mcrypt \ libapache2-mod-php5 \

&& apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV APACHE_RUN_USER www-data ENV APACHE_RUN_GROUP www-data ENV APACHE_LOG_DIR /var/log/apache2


EXPOSE 80

CMD ["/usr/sbin/apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

Comment: What is the path to the file (from inside the container)? Is that directory visible to Apache?

Answer (score 0):

I checked the error log in the container and I noticed that httpd was looking for the file in the wrong path. The path in the container was `/var/www`. Once I mapped it like: `-v /home/dev/www:/var/www` it started working.

Hopefully this may help future newbies to docker.